# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_PREVIEW_SESSION_ITEMS_SESSIONS"

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, session-preview

Given: trying to fix XPM in existing installation (means: [configuring anew](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3C70F892-69F4-4FEE-922D-39F1AFEBD539) is not currently an option).

Clicking [Update Session Preview] after considerable timeout gives an error notification in CME:

```
Unable to update or add Binaries using OData Service.
An error occurred while processing this request.
[..]
Unable to read session data!
```

In cd_core*.log it corresponds to the following excerpt:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_PREVIEW_SESSION_ITEMS_SESSIONS".
The conflict occurred in database "*broker_db_em*", table "dbo.PREVIEW_SESSIONS", column 'PREVIEW_SESSION_ID'.
```

Did so far:

1. Checked that a relevant [configuration files match](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/439/24) between website and webservice
2. Experimented with [<Timeout> parameter](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/1857/24) of the Wrapper config
3. Found out that exactly the same error can be forced manually by trying to INSERT into **PREVIEW_SESSION_ITEMS** when parent record in **PREVIEW_SESSIONS** doesn't exist.

The last point gives a hint that somehow **PREVIEW_SESSIONS** table is cleared asynchronously while **PREVIEW_SESSION_ITEMS** is still being populated. But i wasn't able to find what causes the former table to be truncated.

Thus my question: what is the possible cause of this error?

My guesses:

1. Incorrect configuration
2. Products version mismatch
3. Something else environment-specific.

Any clue or possible direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error you are getting

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

```
"FK_PREVIEW_SESSION_ITEMS_SESSIONS".
The conflict occurred in database "*broker_db_em*", table "dbo.PREVIEW_SESSIONS", column 'PREVIEW_SESSION_ID'.
```

As you already mention, is an inconsistency in the database

I would suggest to recreate the "*broker_db_em*" database if possible and monitor the tables PREVIEW_SESSION_ITEMS and PREVIEW_SESSIONS. That will be the faster to fix the issue.

A record should be deleted from Both tables should at the same time.

In the past I have faced similar inconsistency issues (not related to the XPM / Broker preview database), but with the Broker when for instance was pointed accidentally from a different environment, so I think the best is to start with a fresh "*broker_db_em*"

Comment: Thanks Miguel. Coincidentally, did what you're suggesting: monitored these 2 particular tables, up to the point when parent record got deleted, but there were still attempt to populate PREVIEW_SESSION_ITEMS with the same (by now nonexisting) session id.

I'll experiment with recreating DB. Could you please suggest, is there any useful info that might be lost while dropping *broker_db_em*? My impression it's just merely a caching store, so nothing except for some short-lived info should be lost <= is it correct?

Comment: That is correct, we are not loosing important information when recreating the Dabatase. Preview Database contains information related to the content / pages within the preview session and shouldn't affect the final site. Once you switch to the new Database, monitor the tables again. If information is deleted from one table and not from the other using the new created Database still brings the same issue, I would suggest to open a ticket with customer support, as seems the clean-up process is not executed completely